# Encrypt SVN to store passwords

Tags: encryption, passwords, redhat-enterprise-linux, svn, git-svn

could anyone advise how to encrypt SVN (amazon Linux 2) , Plan to encrypt or disable the SVN from asking if unencrypted passwords should be stored? We never want a user to be able to do that.

Is there possibility that users can bypass it and store their password in a plain text file anyway. If we disable the feature in the client binary, they'll download or compile a different client.

Is encrypt the users' home directory. to protect the passwords as well as the data will work ? If so how to do that ?

```
svn, version 1.7.14 (r1542130)
   compiled Oct  7 2020, 22:48:31

which svn
/bin/svn

whereis svn
svn: /usr/bin/svn /usr/share/man/man1/svn.1.gz
```

Is this solve my problem?

```
~/.subversion/servers:

[global]
# Password / passphrase caching parameters:
store-passwords = no
store-plaintext-passwords = no

[root@ip-10-0-16-165 auth]#

vi ~/.subversion/servers

[global]

store-passwords = yes

store-plaintext-passwords = no

In ~/.subversion/config

[auth]

store-passwords = yes

store-auth-creds = yes

password-stores = gnome-keyring , kwallet
```

what is the best approach here ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you (and users) should encrypt the password files and add this encrypted file to svn. For example you can [encrypt with](https://linuxwebdevelopment.com/encrypt-files-openssl/) `openssl`:

Encrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -in file1 -out file1_encrypted
```

Decrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -in file1_encrypted -out file1
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic , can you please  explain a bit  with the user group !

Comment: uzsolt , With the openssh solution are we decrypting the password from the file each time we need to use it? The Gnome keyring solution sounds like it would be easy for our developers to use. Do in your opinion is security issues with that? what is the best advise here ?

Comment: You can use keyfile. But if you add the keyfile to your repository everyone decrypt the files. I'm using a small script in repository which creates a keyfile after a password (for example password's sha-sum).

Comment: Thanks  uzsolt , to be pedantic  can you explain a bit with the example ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/c7e85598664901afae03fedff308736b